# Qt The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)

Tags: qt, dll, compilation, qt-creator, 32bit-64bit

Am trying to compile project found at [uconfig](https://github.com/Robotips/uConfig), I managed to compile the application successfully using 32bit version mingw, yet when I `run` the .exe I get this error `The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)`, I moved all the required DLLs required to `exe` path but still getting same error,
on the other hand, the application starts in `debug mode` in Qt creator normally

Comment: https://www.easeus.com/backup-recovery/this-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching ... the reason was I had another verion x64 of Qt installed and /bin was added to system path. this resulted in conflict between DLLs generated from Qt and ones found in the System path

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same problem by running them as adminstrator (properties/compatability/Run as Admin)